# I can't get numbers to be output the way I want in C#

Tags: c#, loops, numbers, console-application

I want to input a number between 1-100 and the console should write all numbers from input number to 101. If I input a number that is between 1-100 the program should close. I am having trouble getting the program to close when I input 0 or 101. It either freezes or includes 0 if I input 0 and just writes 101 if 101 is input. When the numbers are output there is no space between them.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input a number between 1-100");
    Console.Write("");
    string number = Console.ReadLine();
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(number);
    do
    {
        if (x > 0 || x < 101) //I tried switching out || for &&
        {
            Console.Write(x++);
        }
    } while (x != 102);
}
```

Comment: Either use `Console.WriteLine` or output a spacing character if you want the numbers separated. But really, this is confusing code, you should almost certainly use a `for` loop here. You should learn how to debug your code, step through it line by line.

Comment: What is your input and what should be written on console(expected output)

Comment: if you input a number greater than 102 you will be stuck in an endless loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `for` loop with a predefined value.

```cs
for (int x = Convert.ToInt32(number); x < 102; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: this changes the logic by accepting negatve numbers or `0`

Comment: + throws exception if number is not a digit

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the current value of `x` as loop-condition

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number between 1-100");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (x > 0 && x < 101)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x++);
}
```

Comment: with `WriteLine` .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x > 0 || x < 101)
```

this is true for pretty much every number. You want to change || to &&

```
Console.Write(x++);
```

Change this to WriteLine or add an extra space at the end of x++ to get your space between them.

```
while (x != 102);
```

this only checks a single value. if you typed in, for example, 103, you would get an infinity loop. try < 102

Answer (score 0):

This code also handles if user tries to give input that isn't a digit.

```
  int x;
  // read input until user inputs a digit instead of string or etc.
  do
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Input a number between 1-100");
  }
  while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x));

  // exit from program if x isn't between 1 and 100
  if (x < 1 || x > 100)
    return;    

  // else count from given number to 101
  for(int i = x; i < 101; ++i)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a "for" loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a number between 1-100");
Console.Write("");
string number = Console.ReadLine();
int x = Convert.ToInt32(number);
if( x > 0 && x < 101 )
{
   for( int i = x; i <=101; i++ )
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use "do-while" loop, change your code like this:

```
static void Main( string[ ] args )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input a number between 1-100");
    Console.Write("");
    string number = Console.ReadLine();
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(number);
    do
    {
        if (x > 0 && x <= 101) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x++);
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit( 0 ); // when insert 0 or 101
        }
    } while (x < 102);
    Console.ReadKey( ); // when write all numbers, wait for a key to close program
}
```